# Einsum for high dimensions

Tags: python, linear-algebra, numpy-einsum

Considering the 3 arrays below:

```
np.random.seed(0)

X = np.random.randint(10, size=(4,5))
W = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4))
y = np.random.randint(3, size=(5,1))
```

i want to add and sum each column of the matrix X to the row of W ,given by y as index. So ,for example, if the first element in y is 3 , i'll add the first column of X to the fourth row of W(index 3 in python) and sum it. i'll do it over and over until all columns of X are added to the specific row of W and summed.
i could do it in different ways:
1- using for loop:

```
for i,j in enumerate(y):
    W[j]+=X[:,i]
```

2- using the add.at function

```
np.add.at(W,(y.ravel()),X.T)
```

3- but i can't understand how to do it using einsum. 
i was given a solution ,but really can't understand it.

```
N = y.max()+1
W[:N] += np.einsum('ijk,lk->il',(np.arange(N)[:,None,None] == y.ravel()),X)
```

Anyone could explain me this structure? 
1 - (np.arange(N)[:,None,None] == y.ravel(),X). i imagine this part refers to summing the column of X to the specific row of W ,according to y. But where s W ? and why do we have to transform W in 4 dimensions in this case?
2- 'ijk,lk->il' - i didnt understand this either.

i -refers to the rows,
j - columns,
k- each element,
l - what does 'l' refers too?.
if anyone can understand this and explain to me , i would really appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify the problem by dropping one dimension and using values that are easy to verify manually:

```
W = np.zeros(3, np.int)
y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Values in the vector `W` get added values from `X` by looking up with `y`:

```
for i, j in enumerate(y):
    W[j] += X[i]
```

`W` is calculated as `[1, 5, 9]`, (check quickly by hand).

Now, how could this code be vectorized? We can't do a simple `W[y] += X[y]` as `y` has duplicate values in it and the different sums would overwrite each other at indices 1 and 2.

What could be done is to broadcast the values into a new dimension of `len(y)` and then sum up over this newly created dimension.

```
N = W.shape[0]
select = (np.arange(N) == y[:, None]).astype(np.int)
```

Taking the index range of `W` (`[0, 1, 2]`), and setting the values where they match `y` to 1 in a new dimension, otherwise 0. `select` contains this array:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

It has `len(y) == len(X)` rows and `len(W)` columns and shows for every y/row, what index of `W` it contributes to.

Let's multiply X with this array, `mult = select * X[:, None]`:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 5]])
```

We have effectively spread out X into a new dimension, and sorted it in a way we can get it into shape W by summing over the newly created dimension. The sum over the rows is the vector we want to add to `W`:

```
sum_Xy = np.sum(mult, axis=0)  # [1, 5, 9]
W += sum_Xy
```

The computation of `select` and `mult` can be combined with `np.einsum`:

```
# `select` has shape (len(y)==len(X), len(W)), or `yw`
# `X` has shape len(X)==len(y), or `y`
# we want something `len(W)`, or `w`, and to reduce the other dimension
sum_Xy = np.einsum("yw,y->w", select, X)
```

And that's it for the one-dimensional example. For the two-dimensional problem posed in the question it is exactly the same approach: introduce an additional dimension, broadcast the `y` indices, and then reduce the additional dimension with `einsum`.

If you internalize how every step works for the one-dimensional example, I'm sure you can work out how the code is doing it in two dimensions, as it is just a matter of getting the indices right (W rows, X columns).

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explanation. i finally understood it.